# Equivalent sed linux command for AIX

Tags: linux, sed, aix

I've this type of data :

```
xxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
xxxx bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
xxxx ccccccccccccccccccc
xxxx ddddddddddddddddddd
xxxx eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

I want this output :

```
xxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
'' bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
'' ccccccccccccccccccc
'' ddddddddddddddddddd
'' eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

On linux I can do :

```
sed "1 ! s|xxxx|''|" data.txt
```

But when I try this on AIX :

```
sed: 0602-403 1 ! s|xxx|''| is not a recognized function.
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: does it work if you use `sed '1 ! s|xxxx|'\'\''|' data.txt`? `!` inside double quotes might be causing issue, not sure though

Comment: That's very odd; the `!` is a part of the POSIX specification for `sed`, so it ought to work fine.  Using `|` instead of `/` should be fine too.  Spacing around the `1`, `!` and `s` shouldn't matter.  I'd experiment with all those variants; I'd look at the AIX `sed` man page.  It doesn't look as if history substitution is confusing things; the error message almost accurately reflects what you show — there is an `xxx` vs `xxxx` discrepancy, but is that in your transcription or on the machine?  Someone suggested installing GNU `sed`; if that's an option, it may be simplest in the short term…

Comment: The error message is strange - where could the `0602-403` come from? @JonathanLeffler Thanks, nice to know.

Comment: AIX has a message identifier like `0602-403` that can be used to find more information about the specific error — it's normal on AIX, @KamilCuk.  It helps with things like I18N/L10N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've done any AIX.

It might be easier to install GNU sed for your AIX system(s), especially if you think you'll be porting Linux shell code a lot.

Also, it might work to use two sed commands chained using the shell, like:

```
sed -n "1p" < input
sed -n "2,$ s|xxxx|''|p" < input
```

I've not tested that on an AIX system, mind you. It's just a guess.

Comment: You could use `sed 1q input` for the first command.  You could combine the two commands into `sed -n -e '1p' -e "2,$ s/xxxx/''/p"` too, or even (probably) `sed -n -e "1p; 2,$ s/xxxx/''/p"`.  All supposing AIX `sed` behaves reasonably normally, which it probably does, but then the question got asked too.

Comment: `sed -n -e "1p; 2,$ s/xxxx/''/p" data.txt` works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: `sed "2,$ s/xxxx/''/" data.txt` should work too in that case

Answer (score 1):

From the [POSIX specification for `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (Emphasis added):

> A function can be preceded by a '!' character, in which case the function shall be applied if the addresses do not select the pattern space. Zero or more `<blank>` characters shall be accepted before the '!' character. **It is unspecified whether `<blank>` characters can follow the '!' character, and conforming applications shall not follow the '!' character with `<blank>` characters.**

I suspect you're running into that. GNU `sed` allows spaces between, AIX `sed` probably doesn't.

Use `sed "1!s|xxxx|''|" data.txt` instead and I bet it'll work.

I do think the `sed "2,$ s/xxxx/''/" data.txt` suggested in a comment is clearer, though.

Comment: And well done on digging out that quote.  I wondered about that in my comment to the question, but maybe I covered too many possibilities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler From what I've gathered second-hand, AIX utilities follow POSIX to a T and if it says something is optional or unspecified about if it's accepted, it's usually not.

Comment: I suspect that another way of looking at it is that the POSIX committee looked at existing implementations, including IBM/AIX, and wrote the specification so that they all met the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
$ awk -v q="''" 'NR>1{sub(/xxxx/, q)} 1' ip.txt
xxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
'' bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
'' ccccccccccccccccccc
'' ddddddddddddddddddd
'' eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

- `-v q="''"` creates variable `q` with value `''`
- `NR>1` if line number is greater than `1`
- `sub(/xxxx/, q)` replace `xxxx` with content of `q` variable for input line

  - if you always need to replace entire first field, you can use `$1=q` instead of `sub` here
- `1` print contents of input line, which is present in `$0` special variable

Answer (score 0):

You could save first line using shell, and invoke `sed` on the rest:

```
{ IFS= read -r firstline; printf "%s\n" "$firstline"; sed "s|xxxx|''|"; } <input
```